# Need help in connecting 64x32 LED Matrix

Tags: rgb-led

I recently got a 64x32 LED Matrix. However, I'm not sure how to connect it to an arduino uno. I tried following the docs here: https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/32x16-32x32-rgb-led-matrix.pdf, but I can't get my OLED matrix to display the example.

This is my current connection so far:
[image]
(I have the R0 at the top left variant. I tried connecting it to the ESP8266 before and it works well, just that I do not know how to translate the connections to the Arduino UNO) I have a feeling that my connection is wrong since I copied the PI to PO connections from here:
[image]

and I only changed the PI to ESP8266 connections to the adafruit docs connections.

The code I am running is the example testshapes_32x64 from the RGB matrix panel library: https://github.com/adafruit/RGB-matrix-Panel/blob/master/examples/testshapes_32x64/testshapes_32x64.ino

EDIT: Since my connection for the CLK pin is connected to pin 8, I made changes in the code but it is still not working.

x-post from: https://www.reddit.com/r/arduino/comments/8qgm9x/need_help_in_connecting_a_64x32_oled_matrix_to_an/ and https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=552832.0

Comment: Why do you use connections shown on twitter? Have you tried doing all connections like described in Adafruits documentation, that you linked to? And using the same example code from there?

Comment: @chrisl that connection worked when I connected it to an ESP8266. I tried the connections and the code, but it didn't work.

Comment: @chrisl I even tried the connections from here: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/rgb-panel-hookup-guide but it isn't working

Comment: Jumping in, just wanted to make sure you @Dominic understand - just because different boards are all called Arduino does not mean the code nor electrical connections are compatible.  If you are going to use an Arduino Uno, you should start over with instructions and software specifically for an Arduino Uno.  Unless you completely understand the processor's hardware, the board's hardware and the software including the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If your matrix is the same as mine (32x64) I don't think you can drive it with a UNO. You should use a MEGA. Then follow the wiring supplied by SparkFun and make sure you connect CLK to Pin 11, NOT Pin 8.

Comment: There is NO demand for using an Arduino MEGA! If you read the documentation an Arduino UNO or eq. is sufficient.